# Display image in DataGridView not working properly

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I'm trying to display image in DataGridView control, I used this code:

```
     Dim img As Bitmap
    img = New Bitmap("http://cache.images.globalsportsmedia.com/soccer/teams/75x75/1241.png")
    ' Create the DGV with an Image column
    Dim dt As New DataGridView()
    Me.Controls.Add(dt)
    Dim imageCol As New DataGridViewImageColumn()
    dt.Columns.Add(imageCol)
    ' Add a row and set its value to the image
    dt.Rows.Add()
    dt.Rows(0).Cells(0).Value = img
```

but in this line there is an error: `img = New Bitmap("http://cache.images.globalsportsmedia.com/soccer/teams/75x75/1241.png")`
the compiler show me this message: URI Format doesn't supported.

I am trying to show in the table of the images on the site, how can I overcome this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
Dim request as WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://cache.images.globalsportsmedia.com/soccer/teams/75x75/1241.png")
Dim response = request.GetResponse()
Dim responseStream as Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
Dim bitmap2 as Bitmap = new Bitmap(responseStream)


' Create the DGV with an Image column
// proceed with your code.
```